# Moving a game up or down the SCID database list

Tags: database, scid

Is there a way to move an individual game up or down the database list or give it a new game number in the list?

Comment: The question is tagged SCID, but it would certainly be clearer if it mentioned it in the question itself too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround to organize the games in a database if you don't mind playing a bit with the text files (PGN files) where the games are stored. This works well in **ScidvsPC**:

1. Go to Tools > Export All Filter Games > Export Filter to PGN
2. Use a name for the file you can identify quickly. For example myfile.pgn
3. Open the PGN file with any text editor.
4. Locate the game you want to move. Cut and paste it in the new position you wanted in the file (database). Save and close the text editor.
5. Run the program **pgnscid** as follows: `pgnscid myfile.pgn mybase`
6. This will create a new database with the name `mybase`. The database consists of three files with different extensions: `mybase.sg4`, `mybase.sn4`, and `mybase.si4`.
7. Rename these files with the name you want for your database but keep the extensions. For example: `nepo.sg4`, `nepo.sn4`, and `nepo.si4`.
8. Open the database in **ScidvsPC**.

It is not as easy as just pressing an arrow button that says move UP or DOWN, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

SCID orders the items in the order that imported them. You can modify the sort order in the list of games. Click in the column names to change the sort order or to reset the sort. But you can't change the individual position of a game in the list.

And what columns can be shown, seems to be hard coded. But if you add a collection of games that are numbered, say on the event tag, it is possible to sort that database by that tag.